# install memcache on plesk

Tags: php, memcached, plesk

Can someone help me with some knowledge on how to install memcache on Plesk 10.4.4. I can't seem to find anything about it.

I have all the loadable php modules in /usr/lib/php/modules/

Comment: I found out the way to install it is with yum -y install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing memcache on Plesk 10.4 is the same as you install it on usual server. Depends on your OS it looks like:

```
yum install php-pecl-memcache
```

After that check it with

```
php -m | grep memcache
```